# AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate reports wrong native rate

Tags: google-project-tango

I have a native audio app already running on a lot of Android hardware.  I use JNI to call AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate to get the native sample rate for the audio pipeline (duh).  This is used to initialize OpenSL for audio output.

On the Google Tango device, getNativeOutputSampleRate returns 48khz.  But using that rate yields glitchy audio.  However, if I initialize the OpenSL player with 44.1 kHz, I get proper audio.

The fact that the code works on a lot of other phones types (and older OSes) makes me think it is the device itself that reports the wrong thing.  But, hey, it's probably something I do anyway...

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: Hi Mathieu, are you having this problem only when the Tango features are running?

Comment: I get this problem even when no other front-end app is running.  And my test app is just that, a test app.  The CPU doesn't seem loaded, I get about 10% usage total according to "top".